# Bundle Worker with Webpack 5 without starting the worker

Tags: webpack, web-worker

I want to bundle a WebWorker script using Webpack 5. The way to do this given the current documentation is:

```
const worker = new Worker('./path_to_worker.js', import.meta.url)
```

However I want to start the worker in a different context of where I defined it. I want to get the url string for the worker and actually start it elsewhere.

```
const workerUrl = ... get webpack bundled path to worker...


... somewhere else in the code ...
let worker = new Worker(workerUrl)
```

Dynamic imports could generate the bundle for the Worker, but I am unable to get the url of the imported script so I can pass it to the worker constructor at later moment in the program execution.

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This horrible hack is the best I could come up with at the present time:

```
function getWorkerUrl() {

    class FakeWorker {
       constructor(url: string | URL) {}
    }

    let oldWorker = self.Worker

    // override the default Worker class temporarily to prevent the worker from launching
    //@ts-ignore
    self.Worker = FakeWorker

    // this will generate the worker bundle with a specified name 
    let worker = new Worker(new URL("./worker.ts" /* webpackChunkName: 'bundle-worker.js' */, import.meta.url))

    // determine the path to the bundle
    const url = './path_to_js/bundle-worker.js'

    // restore the original Worker api
    self.Worker = oldWorker

    return url
}
```